# How to rewrite URL with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

What I want to do is to replace `/display_jobs/` in url.

I want to replace `/display_jobs/blabla bla` with url `/somename/blabla bla`.

How can I do this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here. Can you clarify? What is `somename` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

This article discribes the solution in details:

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Basically you need to put the following in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /display_jobs/$ /somename/$1 [NC]
```